# Incorrectly taking something facetious seriously

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for taking something that's meant tongue in cheek seriously? For example trying to prove someone wrong after they taunt you by saying “You couldn't fight your way out of a paper bag”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of being too *literal-minded*, if you're evaluating their expression at its face value instead of with its idiomatic meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You might think of this as a [visual pun](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VisualPun):

> **visual pun** When a phrase which is usually used as a metaphor is instead done, and shown as being performed literally.

For example:

> In one of the *The Naked Gun* films the main character, Frank, says to a bartender "give me the strongest thing you've got", provoking a VERY muscular and oily man in a thong to walk in, flexing his arms. Frank decides against this, and instead asks for a "Black Russian". The bartender just looks at the camera and shakes his head.